# Gnome Shell Memory Leak

Tags: nvidia, 17.10, gnome-shell, top

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 with an Nvidia GTX 1070 and gnome-shell, also I have 16G of memory. Recently the process `gnome-shell` running after a few hours starts taking a lot of memory and the computer starts getting slow. The only options I am left with are restarting gnome-shell or the system.

I restarted gnome shell by using this command `killall -3 gnome-shell` and it did recover some of the memory but it was then that I saw something weird

[image: Used memory more than total]

As you can see here the used memory is more than the total memory. I might be missing something (something that I might not know), can someone please help me make sense of this and also possibly solve the problem of memory hogging by gnome-shell

*Update:*

As Chelmite pointed out in comments, I realized my mistake the used memory is not more than total memory but the problem still exists and will most likely be fixed in the next release of gnome

Comment: I am just saying that the numbers just don't add up

Comment: There is a known bug in gnome-shell in Ubuntu 17.10 - please see [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1672297](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1672297)  The last word that I recall, is that this will be fixed in 18.04

Comment: Great GNOME! I'm applauding standing! It is time to switch to MATE DE or Xfce or other normal desktop environment without bells & whistles and Wayland.

Comment: that's lame.  Oh well, what can we expect, not an LTS

Comment: So basically till then I'll just have to keep killing gnome-shell

Comment: The total shown is 16,293,840 and used is 1,781,036, which is about 11% of the total. (With that many digits, commas help.)

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. You are right the commas do help.

Comment: Sometime, I use ALT+F2 and then just type "r" in the execute command, this reload Gnome Shell a free up few memory. credits go here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/971601/gnome-shell-process-high-ram-usage-in-17-10